# What is equivalent of VersionControlLabel in VSTS REST API

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

My teams projects have been migrated to Git under VSTS. My current project that is not in VSTS has references to VersionControlLabel because the project was written to target TFS API.

I'm currently trying to upgrade my current project to connect to VSTS and I can connect to the project using the following C# code:

```
  VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vstsOrTfsCollectionUrl), new VssClientCredentials());

  //The ProjectHttpClient
   ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();

  //Retrieves a BuildHttpClient so we can interogate the Builds for a given project
  BuildHttpClient buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

  //Get Basic Project - Shallow Reference
  IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = projectClient.GetProjects().Result;

 //Create client for GIT
 GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

 TeamProject theProject = projectClient.GetProject(projectName).Result;

 List<GitRepository> gitRepositoryList = gitClient.GetRepositoriesAsync(theProject.Name).Result;
```

Is there a equivalent of this in the new REST API that Microsoft has released because i would like to access the changeset/commit information of the project(s) that are currently in Git.

Comment: Do you use TFS or VSTS? And What's the VCS do you use, Git or TFVC? And in you c# code,  it seems you are not using `VersionControlLabel`. For the example to use `VersionControlLabel` to query a given label in TFVC repo hosted in TFS, you can refer the blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2005/10/25/displaying-the-labels-on-a-file-including-label-comments/. Besides, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Projects have been migrated to VSTS. The VCS is Git.
I know in my code i am not using VersionControlLabel, there are classes in the project (File extractor) that reference VersionControlLabel and VersionControlServer because the project was designed for TFS hence why its using TFS Client libraries. 
I'd like to know what are the equivilant of these classes in the VSTS client libaries that are offered by Microsoft. 
I want to upgrade my legacy project to use VSTS client libaries without making lots of changes but it seems i will have to unless i am wrong.